# Use JIRA webhook data in Google Script Project

Tags: json, jira, spreadsheet

I am trying to get the following to work: A JSON is sent to my Google Script - Now I want to get specific values from that JSON Message and store them into specific rows of one specific Google Spreadsheet. So far so good, this is what I have :

```
function doPost(response) {

 var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.openById('MY SHEET ID');

  var dataAll = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

  var nR = getNextRow(sheets) + 1;

// RECORD DATA IN SPREADSHEET
 sheets.getRangeByName('timestamp').getCell(nR,1).setValue(new Date());
 sheets.getRangeByName('ticket_id').getCell(nR,1).setValue(dataAll);

}

function getNextRow(sheets) {
  var timestamps = sheets.getRangeByName("timestamp").getValues();
  for (i in timestamps) {
    if(timestamps[i][0] == "") {
    return Number(i);
  break;
 }}}
```

It should store the response and put it into a blank cell of the range "timestamp". But nothing happens at this point.

This is the JSON ( *Body* ) from JIRA:

```
{"timestamp":1483576902984,"webhookEvent":"jira:issue_created","issue_event_type_name":"issue_created","user":{"self":"https://xxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/user?username=admin","name":"admin","key":"admin","emailAddress":"test@mail.at","avatarUrls":{"48x48":"https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/3d238d8be45bd26982fa09ae2f891c3f?d=mm&s=48","24x24":"https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/3d238d8be45bd26982fa09ae2f891c3f?d=mm&s=24","16x16":"https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/3d238d8be45bd26982fa09ae2f891c3f?d=mm&s=16","32x32":"https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/3d238d8be45bd26982fa09ae2f891c3f?d=mm&s=32"},"displayName":"Max Mustermann  [Administrator]","active":true,"timeZone":"Europe/Berlin"},"issue":{"id":"10057","self":"https://xxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/10057","key":"TA-58","fields":{"issuetype":{"self":"https://xxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issuetype/10104","id":"10104","description":"A problem which impairs or prevents the functions of the product.","iconUrl":"https://xxx.atlassian.net/secure/viewavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=10303&avatarType=issuetype","name":"Bug","subtask":false,"avatarId":10303},"timespent":null,"project":{"self":"https://xxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/project/10000","id":"10000","key":"TA","name":"Test Area","avatarUrls":{"48x48":"https://xxx.atlassian.net/secure/projectavatar?avatarId=10324","24x24":"https://xxx.atlassian.net/secure/projectavatar?size=small&avatarId=10324","16x16":"https://xxx.atlassian.net/secure/projectavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=10324","32x32":"https://xxx.atlassian.net/secure/projectavatar?size=medium&avatarId=10324"}},"customfield_10110":null,"fixVersions":[],"customfield_10111":null,"aggregatetimespent":null,"customfield_10112":"Not started","resolution":null,"customfield_10113":null,"customfield_10114":null,"customfield_10104":null,"customfield_10105":null,"customfield_10106":null,"customfield_10107":null,"customfield_10108":null,"customfield_10109":null,"resolutiondate":null,"workratio":-1,"lastViewed":null,"watches":{"self":"https://xxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/TA-58/watchers","watchCount":0,"isWatching":false},"created":"2017-01-05T01:41:42.903+0100","priority":{"self":"https://xxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/priority/3","iconUrl":"https://xxx.atlassian.net/images/icons/priorities/medium.svg","name":"Medium","id":"3"},"customfield_10100":null,"customfield_10101":null,"customfield_10102":null,"customfield_10103":null,"labels":[],"timeestimate":null,"aggregatetimeoriginalestimate":null,"versions":[],"issuelinks":[],"assignee":null,"updated":"2017-01-05T01:41:42.903+0100","status":{"self":"https://xxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/status/10000","description":"","iconUrl":"https://xxx.atlassian.net/","name":"To Do","id":"10000","statusCategory":{"self":"https://xxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/statuscategory/2","id":2,"key":"new","colorName":"blue-gray","name":"To Do"}},"components":[],"timeoriginalestimate":null,"description":"super alles neu","timetracking":{},"customfield_10005":null,"attachment":[],"aggregatetimeestimate":null,"summary":"super alles neu","creator":{"self":"https://xxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/user?username=admin","name":"admin","key":"admin","emailAddress":"test@mail.at","avatarUrls":{"48x48":"https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/3d238d8be45bd26982fa09ae2f891c3f?d=mm&s=48","24x24":"https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/3d238d8be45bd26982fa09ae2f891c3f?d=mm&s=24","16x16":"https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/3d238d8be45bd26982fa09ae2f891c3f?d=mm&s=16","32x32":"https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/3d238d8be45bd26982fa09ae2f891c3f?d=mm&s=32"},"displayName":"Max Mustermann  [Administrator]","active":true,"timeZone":"Europe/Berlin"},"subtasks":[],"reporter":{"self":"https://xxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/user?username=admin","name":"admin","key":"admin","emailAddress":"test@mail.at","avatarUrls":{"48x48":"https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/3d238d8be45bd26982fa09ae2f891c3f?d=mm&s=48","24x24":"https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/3d238d8be45bd26982fa09ae2f891c3f?d=mm&s=24","16x16":"https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/3d238d8be45bd26982fa09ae2f891c3f?d=mm&s=16","32x32":"https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/3d238d8be45bd26982fa09ae2f891c3f?d=mm&s=32"},"displayName":"Max Mustermann  [Administrator]","active":true,"timeZone":"Europe/Berlin"},"customfield_10000":"{}","aggregateprogress":{"progress":0,"total":0},"customfield_10001":null,"customfield_10115":null,"customfield_10116":"0|i0005r:","environment":null,"duedate":null,"progress":{"progress":0,"total":0},"comment":{"comments":[],"maxResults":0,"total":0,"startAt":0},"votes":{"self":"https://xxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/TA-58/votes","votes":0,"hasVoted":false},"worklog":{"startAt":0,"maxResults":20,"total":0,"worklogs":[]}}}}
```

However, I don't want to have the whole JSON in my cell, I only want to have specific obejcts/id from within the JSON. How do I call them ?

Comment: this post needs lots of edits; there is too much jargon going on and no one cares where the JSON is coming from and what properties your interested in no offense. Lets start by stating what variable stores the JSON...

Comment: `getCell()` should get you the cell of your choice, `setValue()` will set the corresponding cell to whatever data you want; That's all there is to it.

Comment: Thanks @Rafael - getCell and setValue is what i already have and it works, but how do I get one specific object from the JSON and set it as value for a cell ? ...the JSON is stored in req, right ? I also tried `var dataAll = JSON.parse(req.getContentText());
  var data = dataAll.timestamp;

 sheets.getRangeByName('ticket_id').getCell(nR,1).setValue(data);
  
}`

Comment: It should be in the server response not your request.  If you negotiate `application/json` the js engine will call `JSON.parse()` for you and you'll get back a regular object that you can index like any other js object. If your `doPost()` function is handling the server response, you should not be calling the parameter `req`; it should be called `response` because that is what the server is responding from the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After tons of research, this is a solution that works for me (in my case):

```
function doPost(response) {

  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SHEET_ID');

// retrieve data from JIRA Payload and store them into "data"

  var json = response.postData.contents;
  var data = JSON.parse(json);

// index values from "data" and store them into seperate variables
// for example:   
  var ticket_id = data.issue.key;
  var priority_name = data.issue.fields.priority.name;
  var summary = data.issue.fields.summary;
```

---

This two lines:

```
var json = response.postData.contents;
var data = JSON.parse(json);
```

Made it possible to read the `body` and index all the specific parameters I want.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is an example:**

```
/*
 * webhookHandler: JIRA webhook callback function
 */
function webhookHandler(response) {
    var data = response.getAs("application/json");
    //logs out data in dev console
    console.log(data);

    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("<spreadsheet id>");
    var cellRange = spreadsheet.getRangeByName("<some range name>");
    var cell = cellRange.getCell(0 /*row index*/, 0/*column index*/);

    cell.setValue(data.ticket_id/*index the JSON object returned by response*/);
}
```

[UrlFetchApp Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)

[SpreadsheetApp Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app/)

Comment: That's awesome ! But in my case, I don't have `"<some jira url>"` , I'm using JIRA webhooks to send the JSON automatically whenever I do stuff in JIRA - to the Google Script. How would your code example work with that ? I really appreciate your thoughts :)

Comment: Thanks @Rafael ! This worked for me `var json = response.postData.contents;
var data = JSON.parse(json);`

Answer (score 1):

For those of you who wonder why it's not working. Allow me to explain.

The normal setup for this to work is to deploy your apps script as web app, then you can use your apps script's url to create a jira webhook. So when a defined event is triggered (for example when a ticket is created), webhook will post a json file to your apps script, then if you have set up a doPost function, it will run that function and you can grab the info from json file. Below is a simple example.

```
function doPost(e) {
  // Parse the JSON data from the JIRA webhook
  var data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  
  // Get the JIRA ticket number from the webhook data
  var ticketNumber = data.issue.key;
}
```

The problem arises when you are using a company google account, because when you deploy your app, the only setup you can set is likely `Allow everyone in your org to access` the app. When you have this setup in place, the apps script app won't get the post from jira. jira webhook currently has no options to include an auth method so you can't use webhook for your company account.

The only way atm (feel free to correct me) is to schedule the apps script to run to get data from jira, but it might become very problematic if you need to run this script frequently.